# Adding new files in SVN

Tags: svn

I have to replace new DLLs from src/lib/dlls to SVN. I added the DLLs to SVN from the `dlls` folder. For committing the changes to SVN, should I commit the `src` folder or the `lib` folder to see the changes in SVN?. Also, how do I handle the missing DLLs (the DLLs that I replaced)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like `dlls` folder was already in SVN, you can commit the dlls folder itself. Else you can from `lib`.

Answer (score 1):

both will work.
committing at an upper level will commit all the changes made at lower level directories unless --non-recursive switch is supplied

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Comment: Thanks. Since I am replacing the dlls what do I do for missing dlls message from SVN?.